# Simple Toast with definable attribution area text

Tags: c#, wpf, toast, .net-4.8

I am using C# WPF .net 4.8.1.
I want to show a notification Toast with my app and so far everything works as intended, but one little, but important, thing:

[image: toast]

There is a Dev-Debug as Title not what I thought (Header Title) would be shown. And even worse, the documentation states, that where this Dev-Debug is shown would be the "Attribution Area". But even the AttributionText is not shown where I want it. And when I click on the notifications area in Windows it looks like this:
[image: notify area]
So the Dev-Debug is used as some kind of grouping item where all toasts are put together. But I wanted only a simple one with the name of my application and a simple message.

This is my code:
App.xaml.cs:

```
ToastNotificationManagerCompat.OnActivated += toastArgs =>
{
    ToastArguments args = ToastArguments.Parse(toastArgs.Argument);
    ValueSet userInput = toastArgs.UserInput;
    Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(delegate
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Toast activated. Args: " + toastArgs.Argument);
    });
};
```

And the toast itself:

```
public Toast()
{
    ToastContentBuilder test = new ToastContentBuilder();
    test.AddAttributionText("TestAttributionText");
    test.AddHeader(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),"TestHeaderTitle", "TestHeaderArgument");
    test.AddArgument("TestKey", "TestValue");
    test.AddText("TestText");
    test.Show(toast =>
    {
        toast.ExpirationTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2);
    });
}
```

Has someone an idea how to show just a simple header with a simple text?

Comment: AFAIK, the title (app name) is the OS's current feature of toast notification. There was no such title in older Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might not see this in older versions of Windows, but the app's name (which I guess is the "Dev-Debug" in your case) and icon are always displayed in the attribution area on Windows 11. You cannot remove it.

This is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/adaptive-interactive-toasts?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077).

Comment: Hm, typically MS b*******. I tested it in our release build and there was a text with the name of our app followed by "obfuscated with...". So it pulls the app name out of some meta data that no sane person ever uses... *sigh* ok, so we have to use another approach. This is not usable. But thanks for the answer.